# Proper way to set up select with relational data in knockout?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm wanting to make a select box with an array of locations in it, and the selected location is bound to an observable. My question is: am I doing it the right way? It seems odd to me to make an observable array with the data in it, then have to bind the actual value to another variable so that I can dynamically create the select box. Is there a better way to do it?

Also, in the end I'm going to have to make 7 of these as well (one for each day of the week). How would that effect things? I'd assume my location_id would become an `observableArray`, but would I still build the selects the same way?

Here is my (somewhat pseudo) code:

```
var TimeEntriesModel = function (locations) {
    var self = this;

    self.locations = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(locations, function (location) {
        return new LocationViewModel(location);
    }));

    location_id = ko.observable(434051968);
}

var LocationViewModel = function(location) {
    var self = this;

    self.location_id = location.id;
    self.location_name = location.name;
    self.location_abbrv = location.abbreviation;
}

var entriesModel = new TimeEntriesModel(locationsdata);

ko.applyBindings(entriesModel);


var locationsdata = [
    {
        "id": "434051968",
        "name": "Serbia",
        "abbreviation": "SERBIA"
    },
    {
        "id": "434051969",
        "name": "Michigan - Detroit",
        "abbreviation": "DT"
    },
    {
        "id": "434051970",
        "name": "California - Los Angeles",
        "abbreviation": "LS"
    },
    {
        "id": "434051971",
        "name": "Macedonia",
        "abbreviation": "MACEDONIA"
    }];
```

And the select:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: $root.locations, value: $root.location_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-bind="value: location_id, text: location_name, attr: {title: location_abbrv}" ></option>
</select>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5nDs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly valid and if you want to make code a little bit cleaner then arrayMap code can seprated like :-

```
var locationsArray= ko.utils.arrayMap(locations, function (location) {
    return new LocationViewModel(location);
});
self.locations = ko.observableArray(locationsArray);
```

And

```
location_id = ko.observable(434051968);//location id is not bind to self so you can not see observable behavior of location id.
```

do like this.

```
self.location_id = ko.observable(434051968);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5nDs/2/

Comment: Alright, I just wanted confirmation. It seems counter intuitive to what I'm used to.

Answer (score 0):

If the data of locations is not going to change while the program is running, there is no need for it to be an observableArray (or observable).

It might be worth keeping in mind that an observableArray is just a "regular" observable, with some extra utility functions. I don't know what exactly you are building, but you might need an "array of observables", and not an "observable array" for the results.